# Database Mirroring - App Can't Connect to Mirror - Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, connection-string, failover, database-mirroring

I have an application that can connect to the Principal, but can't connect to the Mirror during a failover.

(Note to moderator: please let me know if this question is more appropriate for serverfault.  I posted it here because I found more questions similar to this issue than on serverfault.)

This is the error I receive when my application attempts to connect to the Mirror after a failover:

```
Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53].
Cannot open database "MY_DB_NAME" requested by the login. The login failed.
```

I am familiar with the fact that when initially connected to the Principal, the name of the Mirror server is cached to be used during the failover and that the failover partner I specify in my connection string is only used if the initial connection to the Principal fails.

This clearly describes the problem I'm having:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2010/12/15/running-a-database-mirror-setup-with-the-sqlbrowser-service-off-may-produce-unexpected-results.aspx

...but the SQL Browser Service is running and I can't figure out why the name won't resolve when connecting to the mirror.

I'm assuming there is a service that must be running to enable NetBIOS name resolution that is not running, because this is what I see in WireShark consistently without a response from the Mirror:

```
Source       Destination  Protocol Length Info
10.200.3.111 10.200.5.255 NBNS     92     Name query NB SQL-02-SVR-<00>
```

**Question 1:** What could be causing the problem? ;-)

**Question 2:** I really don't want to enable NetBIOS (for security reasons) and I'm using IP addresses (no FQDNs) in the mirror configuration and in the connection string.  Given the caching behavior of the mirror partner when connecting to the Principal, is there a way to force TCP/IP to be used so the value that is cached is the IP address and not the name?  Do I need to run the SQL Server Browser/Computer Browser services?

The configuration:

- App Is Delphi XE2 using SDAC 6.5.9 (I don't think this is relevant to the component I'm using because it works in other installations with mirroring and has no issues)
- SQL Server 2012 Enterprise installed as a default instance on Principal, Mirror and Witness in a non-domain configuration using certificate authentication.
- Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 64-bit on all machines
- Firewalls disabled on Principal, Mirror and Client (where app is running)
- TCP/IP and Named Pipes enabled on Principal and Mirror
- SQL Server Browser service running on Mirror
- Computer Browser service running on Mirror
- Mirroring is configured for automatic failover with a witness and works properly (I can fail back and forth between mirror and principal without issue)
- SQL Native Client 2012 installed on Client machine
- Same app login (with same SID and user rights) exists on both Principal and Mirror
- Correct server, failover partner, database name, user name and password verified in my app log
- In connection string, principal server is 'tcp:10.200.3.15,1433' and failover partner is 'tcp:10.200.3.16,1433' using the SQL Native client
- I can ping both servers from the Client machine
- NetBIOS over TCP/IP has been enabled in the adapter under the WINS tab (on the Mirror and Client machines)

I've been able to get the application working with mirroring on several other installations, but this one is baffling me.

Comment: I removed the Delphi tag, because the question has nothing to do with Delphi at all. It's strictly a SQL Server issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, which was that the customer had the Principal and Mirror in one VLAN and the Client(s) in another.  Although the IP addressing scheme was the same, the policy for communication between the VLANs prevented broadcast messages, which is why the NetBIOS query was failing on the client.  A WINS or DNS server will be implemented to resolve this issue.

However, I am still interested in an answer to my Question #2, above.

Comment: Do you finally have some resolution ? Mind to share. We are running into the same kind of problem right now.